# Git Master Branch Location Configuration

Tags: git

I am not too used to using git for Windows.
I seem to have accidently set the whole user folder on Windows as my git master branch. How can i undo this without having to move the entire Users folder?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you did?

Comment: Nvm i think i solved it. A few weeks ago i unintentionally created a repository in eclipse which had my users folder as a file base. This led to some flickering in the Visual Studio team explorer. But i managed to delete it in eclipse. Thanks for your help though